# Blazor WebAssembly AuthenticationState has empty identity

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to get user information in Blazor WebAssembly.

This is in my Program.cs:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
                .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

            // Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("Morf.ServerAPI"));

            
            await builder.Services.AddODataService<MorfODataServiceContext>(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
            var unhandledExceptionSender = new UnhandledExceptionSender();
            var unhandledExceptionProvider = new UnhandledExceptionProvider(unhandledExceptionSender);
            builder.Logging.AddProvider(unhandledExceptionProvider);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IUnhandledExceptionSender>(unhandledExceptionSender);
            builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();
            builder.Services.AddMudServices();
            builder.Services.AddLocalization(o => o.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
            var host = builder.Build();
            await host.SetDefaultCulture();
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
```

And in component I inject AuthenticationState and get User.Identity but Name and Claims are empty.  I able to get IsAuthenticated property but not other information. On the server side I use default Microsoft Identity.

Can you please tell me where something might be wrong?

Comment: Is there any error messages sir?

Comment: No, no errors..